# UnitTest Mock: Problema con DbSet para llenar los datos de la entidad

Tags: c#, test

Un saludo, Bueno espero me puedan orientar con un problema que tengo con una prueba de unidad a la hora de llenar unos datos y que se vean reflejados en la entidad al llamar el metodo, a continuación presento el codigo utilizado:

**Grupos.cs**:

```
namespace ServiceApplication
{
    public partial class Grupos
    {
        private readonly Lazy<IGruposAsociadosAlRol> GruposAsociadosAlRol;
        private readonly Lazy<IUsuariosAsociadosAlGrupo> UsuariosAsociadosAlGrupo;

        public Grupos(
            IMainContext repositoryContext,            
            IGruposAsociadosAlRol gruposAsociadosAlRol,
            IUsuariosAsociadosAlGrupo usuariosAsociadosAlGrupo
        ) : base(new Grupos(repositoryContext))
        {
            this.GruposAsociadosAlRol = new Lazy<IGruposAsociadosAlRol>(gruposAsociadosAlRol);
            this.UsuariosAsociadosAlGrupo = new Lazy<IUsuariosAsociadosAlGrupo>(usuariosAsociadosAlGrupo);
        }
        
        protected override void ValidationsToDelete(Grupos entity)
        {
            using var tran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
            {
                //Me llega vacio por que ??
                this.GruposAsociadosAlRol.Value.DeleteRange(remover => remover.IdGrupo == entity.Id);
                //Me llega vacio por que ??
                this.UsuariosAsociadosAlGrupo.Value.DeleteRange(remover => remover.IdGrupo == entity.Id);
                tran.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Grupos.Test.cs**:

```
namespace UnitTestsProject.Tests
{        
    [TestClass]
    public partial class Grupos : BaseTest<ServiceApplication.Interfaces.IGrupos>
    {        
        private readonly Mock<IMainContext> adaptadorGrupos;
        
        private readonly Mock<IGruposAsociadosAlRol> gruposAsociadosAlRol;
        private readonly Mock<IUsuariosAsociadosAlGrupo> usuariosAsociadosAlGrupo;

        public Grupos()
        {            
            adaptadorGrupos = new Mock<IMainContext>();

            gruposAsociadosAlRol = new Mock<IGruposAsociadosAlRol>();
            usuariosAsociadosAlGrupo = new Mock<IUsuariosAsociadosAlGrupo>();

            DbSet<Grupos> myDbSet = GetQueryableMockDbSet(DataTest.GetListGroup()) ;
            DbSet<GruposAsociadosAlRol> myDbSet2 = GetQueryableMockDbSet(DataTest.GetListGruposAsociadosAlRol());
            DbSet<UsuariosAsociadosAlGrupo> myDbSet3 = GetQueryableMockDbSet(DataTest.GetListUsuariosAsociadosAlGrupo();

            adaptadorGrupos.Setup(item => item.Set<Grupos>()).Returns(myDbSet);
            adaptadorGrupos.Setup(item => item.Set<GruposAsociadosAlRol>()).Returns(myDbSet2);
            adaptadorGrupos.Setup(item => item.Set<UsuariosAsociadosAlGrupo>()).Returns(myDbSet3);

            AddAdaptadorMock();
        }
        
        [TestMethod]
        public void Delete()
        {
            var obj = new Grupos { 
                Id = 1
            };

            adaptadorGrupos.Setup(item => item.SaveChanges()).Returns(1);

            IGrupos BusinessRulesGrupos = new Grupos(
                adaptadorGrupos.Object,
                gruposAsociadosAlRol.Object, 
                usuariosAsociadosAlGrupo.Object
            );

            var objReturn = BusinessRulesGrupos.Delete(obj);

            ////Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(objReturn != null && objReturn.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Mi duda es por que mis dos objetos que estan en la clase **Grupo** me llegan vacios a pesar de que ya asigne los datos al **repositoryContext** en mi prueba unitaria ?? pues ya con el metodo asignado al **repositoryContext** (adaptadorGrupos.Setup()) asigno los datos que estaria trabajando.